# How to use initialvalue with ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the initialvalue but I'm getting the below error:

[image]

I'm doing this:

UPDATE

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.produtorServices
        .search(
            (widget.cpf))
        .then((usersFromServer) {
      setState(() {
        users = usersFromServer;

      });
TextEditingController nameController =
            TextEditingController(text: user[0].name);
    });
  }.
.
.
child: ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                  CustomInput(
                  label: 'New Name',
                  controller: nameController ,
.
.
```

I tried setting the initial value this way.

When I do print(users[0].name) I get the username correctly.

**How do I set this value in the input?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both initial value and controller at the same time.If you just want to render the data in the UI, initial value will suffice.

```
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                  CustomInput(
                  label: 'New Name',
                  initialValue: filteredUsers[index].name!,
.
.
```

Comment: I made the suggested change but got "Unexpected null value".

Comment: Make sure the ```filteredUsers``` list has been initialised. If you fetching the data from Api, use ```setState```.

Comment: Yes, filterUsers is started and I am getting the API information correctly.
If I remove the controller and leave only the initialValue, how can I get the value that is set by default in the input ?

Comment: In that case, you hav eto scrap the initial value and use controller instead. Set the data obtained from the response in the initState.

Comment: I tried this, but the value is not set in the input! - 
TextEditingController nomeEdicacaoController = TextEditingController(text: users[0].name!);